# Bootstrap not working in asp.net mvc view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a asp.net register view and I have used bootstrap to get a responsive page
but when I run the page in a browser it looks the same a sit did before I added the bootstrap classes. I have tried using the same  classes in an asp.net webform and it works fine. the code for my view is bellow:

```
    @model JustBlog.Core.Objects.User
       @{
   Layout = null;
        }

     <!DOCTYPE html>

 <html>
  <head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Register</title>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js">    </script>
<script         src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/jquery.validate.min.j     s"></script>
<script         src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js">       </script>

   </head>
    <body style="background-color:#EEE7CD;">
     <div class="container-fluid">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <div class="row-fluid">

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="page-header" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                            <h3>Register Here</h3>
                        </div>
                        <table class="table">                             


                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.firstName)
                                            </td>
                                            <td >
                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.firstName)
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.firstName)
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.lastName)
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.lastName)
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="color: Red">
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.lastName)
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="color: Red">
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>


                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Username)
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username)
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="color: Red">
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Username)
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="color: Red">
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="submit" value="Register" />

                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                      @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>

                           </table>


     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
    }
   </div>
   </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Did you reference bootstrap css in your page?

Comment: Your code does not include the bootstrap files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not adding the scripts and stylesheets to reference Bootstrap. You need to make your site get references to Bootstrap library.

Please see below. You could use the CDN to link it, just add the links below to your head section and you can go without downloading Bootstrap locally.
See more alternatives at: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```